# wp_insert_post disable HTML filter

Tags: security, wp-insert-post

I have input value "`<iframe>....</iframe>`" (param 'post_content'). When i execute wp_insert_post, function cut off my tag.

How to disable HTML filter in **wp_insert_post** ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use call kses_remove_filters() before saving and call kses_init_filters() afterwards, but pay attention it will also remove filtering from title, excerpt and comments,
So what you should do is just unset the content filters.

```
// Post filtering
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

and after the post is saved

```
// Post filtering
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

Comment: how will the `<iframe>` show up in the posts? and what other tags can I insert ? if I use this filter ?